# How to add the "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" request header to a POST request in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, cors, backend

So, I am trying to set the "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", using the `HttpContext.Request.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");` , but it will only work for my GET requests, but not for my POST ones, and i don't know why.

I've also tried to set those in Startup.cs, as so:

```
 services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("ApiCorsPolicy", builder =>
            {
                builder
                       .WithOrigins("My_Web_App")
                       .AllowCredentials()
                       .AllowAnyMethod()
                       .AllowAnyHeader();
            }));
```

And then use it in Configure with `app.UseCors("ApiCorsPolicy");`

That's the code from my controller, so nothing fancy in here, I think:

```
   [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    [EnableCors("ApiCorsPolicy")]
    public class UserController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IUserService _userService;
        public UserController(IUserService userService)
        {
            _userService = userService;
        }

        [HttpPost("RegisterUser")]
        public void GetTournaments([FromBody] UserDTO user)
        {

            HttpContext.Request.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
            _userService.RegisterUser(user);
        }

    }
```

My question is, why I can't put the "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" header using the `Headers.add` method( Which works for my GET requests ) ? If that is not the correct approach to it, then how to do it ?
Thanks!

Edit:
I've added all my Startup file, as requested:

```
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

      
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("ApiCorsPolicy", builder =>
            {
                builder
                       .WithOrigins("http://"MyIpAddressHere"/")
                       .AllowAnyMethod()
                       .AllowAnyHeader();
            }));

            var mapperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(mc =>
            {
                mc.AddProfile(new MappingGeneral());
            });

            IMapper mapper = mapperConfig.CreateMapper();
            services.AddSingleton(mapper);

            services.AddSingleton<ITournamentService, TournamentService>();
            services.AddSingleton<IUserService, UserService>();
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "my_app", Version = "v1" });
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "my_app v1"));
            }

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseCors("ApiCorsPolicy");

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });


        }
    }
```

Comment: The `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` is [a response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Credentials)

Comment: it doesen't work either, if i try to Response.headers.add it

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
.WithOrigins("My_Web_App")
```

to

```
.WithOrigins("http://localhost....") //your web app url

//your Url shouldn't end with "/"
```

and remove from code:

```
//sometimes it interfers with token if you have
 .AllowCredentials()

// you don't need this at all
  HttpContext.Request.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
```

Your UseCors should be after UseRouting but before UseAuthorization.

and remove from your controller:

```
 [EnableCors("ApiCorsPolicy")]
```

Comment: I've already done the first change with the .WithOrigins("http://localhost...."), and tried to remove both of them at the second step, and still not working as it should.

Comment: And your Url shouldn't have the last "/".

Comment: In there I have this: .WithOrigins("http://`MY IP HERE/`")

Comment: It works for all my get requests, but not for post

Comment: @manta No. You should have .WithOrigins("http://MY IP HERE") . It shouldn't end with /. And I am not sure about IP address, never tried it.  But maybe it working.

Comment: Sorry, I tried it without the last /, and it still doesn't work. I use my IP because I fixed another problem with the CORS policy, in which I couldn't send cookies if I didn't had my front-end app and back-end app on the same "domain" per-se.

Comment: What is your full post url?

Comment: And I don't understand why you can't put here your domain url. It has nothing to do with your cookies. You can use requests with ip .

Comment: That was the only thing that worked. I can't send cookies to my localhost, but I can when I'm using my IP. And now I can send them, but I have this problem, where my POST endpoints don't have the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header set

Comment: Yes, I edited and added it to the initial question body.

Comment: I see you still keep the last "/"?  And I was wondering why do you use this: [HttpPost("RegisterUser")]
        public void GetTournaments([FromBody] UserDTO user) . Why you just  don't change it to: [Route("~/User/RegisterUser")]
        public IActionResult RegisterUser([FromBody] UserDTO user) { ... return Ok()}

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about it. I've change it now, but still not working. I get the same error as before ( the one about the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header being " " )

Comment: @manta It will be just waist of time if you trying to accomlish two task in the same time. One step in a time.  Forget about cookies, and try to make working without them. After this you can only think about cookies. But I never heard that somebody was using cookies for API.